# How to display an Alert box without cancel and ok button?

Tags: android

I like to create an Alert box without ok and cancel button. The alert box should display for a particular period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example

remove the button in the example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
"AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alertbox.setMessage("Do You want to Save?");
alertbox.create();
alertbox.show();"
```

it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Toast:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.my_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class AlarmManager or TimerTask to display the number for a limited time. 
To remove the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons, you can use the LayoutInflater.

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize the dialog using [this tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example).
2. Then remove that button in XML
3. Then add a handler -- [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) -- and close the dialog after a certain duration.

or

1. Use a toast message.